# How can I convert a fraction to a string that can be used in a file name?

Tags: string-manipulation

I want add an index to the file names of my exported images, so I'm using `ToString`. But I have a problem when my index is a fraction, because then the generated file name includes characters not recognised by my system.

Is it possible to make $2\pi/5$ become, for example, `2Pi--5` or something similar when converting it to a string?

Comment: Use `Numerator[]` and `Denominator[]` to separate fractions into its components.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it would be something simple. Thank you, I guess I should improve my searching skills.

Comment: Then, you should now be able to answer your own question. :)

Comment: Wait, you mean "answer" literally, like edit my post? I'm quite new, sorry if it's a many-time-repeated question...

Of course the problem is solved, if that's what you meant :)

Comment: No, don't edit your post; use the answer box to answer your question as soon as the system allows you to.

Comment: `StringReplace[SpokenString[2 Pi/5], " " -> "_"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need `InputForm` if you want to convert `π` to `Pi`.

If you want parentheses, then

```
2 π/5 // ToString[#, InputForm] & // StringReplace[#, "/" :> "--"] &
```

> "(2*Pi)--5"

or else

```
2 π/5 // ToString[#, InputForm] & // 
  StringReplace[#, {"/" :> "--", "(" :> "", ")" :> ""}] &
```

> "2*Pi--5"